# When I am accessing my column in a dataframe which is of type list, then I am getting the output as str?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

[image]

When I am accessing 2nd column of 0th row which is of type list, but here I am getting string. How Can I get list as the output?

[image]

Comment: `df` display omits quotes, so lists, strings, even arrays may look the same.  And the column dtype is the generic `object`

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been read into your df as a `str` type. To avoid it you may try something along the following lines:

```
from ast import literal_eval
df = pd.read_csv("filepath.csv", converters=({"link": literal_eval}))
```

or

```
df["link"] = df["link"].apply(literal_eval)
```

They will evaluate your str objects to valid python objects

Answer (score 1):

Might this be an actual string that represents the list?

If so, you can apply the following function:

```
s = "['aa', 'bb']"
s = (list(map(lambda x: x[1:-1], s[1:-1].split(', '))))
```

This takes the list's string, cuts the '[,]', and then splits it to its elements using the separator ', '. After that, it trims unnecessary quotation marks using the list(map()) and lambda, and this should be work for you to extract the list.